# Existence of a unique maximizer of a strict quasi-concave function defined over a convex set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, self-learning, convex-analysis

Set $S \subset \mathbb R^2$ is compact and convex. A typical element of $S$ is $s=(s_1,s_2) \in S$. Also, $d \in \mathbb R^2$ is a fixed element such that there exists $s \in S$ such that $s \gt d$. Here  $s \gt d$ means $s_1 \gt d_1$ and $s_2 \gt d_2$
$$\underset{(d_1,d_2)\le(s_1,s_2) \in S}{\overset{}{\operatorname{arg \;\; max}}} \; (s_1-d_1)(s_2-d_2)$$

Let $H(s_1,s_2)=(s_1-d_1)(s_2-d_2)$. Since  $H$ is strictly quasi concave on $\{s \in S: s \gt d \}$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $s \gt d$ and $S$ is convex, so the maximizer of $H$ is unique.

**My question:** I did not get the last part. Why is maximizer of $H$ unique?

Answer (score 3):

*Strict* quasiconcavity means (at least to me) that for any two points $p,q$ in the  domain of $H$ and for every $t\in (0,1)$
$$H(tp+(1-t)q)>\min(H(p),H(q)) \tag1$$
(With nonstrict inequality this is simply quasiconcavity).

If $H$ attains its maximum at two distinct points $p,q$, then (1) immediately yields a contradiction.

Comment: since $t \in (0,1)$, $r=tp+(1-t)q \neq p,q$ and because $H(p)=H(q)$ and $H(p) \geq H(r)$, it leads to contradiction, doesn't it?